# Jquery Dialogue

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am trying to call the below method twice, first time the dailogue opens and i click on yes button in the dialogue, when i make the second call, the control directly hits Close method, without showing the dialogue on the screen.

Kindly help

```
function ConfirmWindow(title, msg, showOkButton) {
    //debugger
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    $($('#ConfirmWindow')).dialog({
        // modal: true,
        title: title,
        height: 175,
        width: 440,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: false,
        open: function() {
            var markup = msg;
            $(this).html(markup);
            $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                .html("<span class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'></span>");
            $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-widget-header")
                .addClass("ConfirmHeaderClass");
            $(this).parent().css("zIndex", 2000);

            if (!showOkButton)
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("Ok")').button().hide();
            else {
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("Yes")').button().hide();
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("No")').button().hide();
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("Cancel")').button().hide();
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            defer.resolve("cancel");
            $(this).dialog('close');

        },
        buttons: {
            Yes: function() {
                defer.resolve("yes");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            No: function() {
                defer.resolve("no");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                defer.resolve("cancel");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Ok: function() {
                defer.resolve("ok");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
        }
    });
    //debugger
    return defer.promise();
}
```

Comment: So you call it both the times by calling the function `ConfirmWindow()` ?

Comment: Yes..i use the same method to call twice

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Jai,there is form, when an user edits something and tries to navigate to copy the existing data, i show him a form dirty popup warning and then if he still like to move away from changes i ask him whthr he likes to copy the data or not..

Comment: thats wrong, because you have this code `$($('#ConfirmWindow')).dialog({})`  inside the function which is initializing thee plugin in. if you run this code second time , you are trying to apply the plugin to already applied element , so you find issues

Comment: i tried to destroy the dialogue, but it removes the dialogue place holder too. Is there any way i can re-instantiate the dialogue for every call to this method